# Apache server stopped working

Tags: php, apache, server

I'm using Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server as a test server. It has stopped working. What I mean is whenever I try to access a page at say x.x.x.x/foo/bar.php my browsers status bar says `waiting for x.x.x.x` and the server never responds.

This is what the error logs at says:

```
[Thu Jun 25 11:30:22 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/index.php on line 28
[Thu Jun 25 11:30:59 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/index.php on line 28
[Thu Jun 25 11:31:20 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DbConnector::dbQuery() in /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/index.php on line 31
[Thu Jun 25 11:57:41 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
[Thu Jun 25 11:59:03 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
[Thu Jun 25 12:15:33 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
[Thu Jun 25 12:31:56 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
[Thu Jun 25 12:49:47 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
[Thu Jun 25 12:50:15 2015] [error] [client 151.80.123.208] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Thu Jun 25 12:56:29 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/
```

I'm just an intern so I only have ftp access to this test server. My supervisor says there is a problem with the code on one of the pages somewhere on the server but he's too busy with something else to fix it right now.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: `[Thu Jun 25 11:30:59 2015] [error] [client 94.200.27.10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/share/drupal6/abdi-test/index.php on line 28` There is the error, what does this line(`28`) contains?

Comment: It contains `module_load_include('php', 'hmm_activities', 'dbconnector');` although I deleted that `index.php` file from the server. The server was rebooted and I did not reupload `index.php`. Even now the server still doesn't work. Do you really think that is the problem?

Comment: If you deleted the file, how come it still gives errors in the file? Could you recheck for the file and the errors?

Comment: I deleted the file _after_ the server stopped working. The server was even rebooted after deleting the file.

Comment: Why did you deleted the file? That's why it isn't working then ..

Comment: The whole server isn't working. Not just the directory that I deleted (yes at this stage I have deleted the whole `/abdi-test`/ directory). Every other directory and the rest of the server is not responding.

Comment: Alright, but it `only` stopped working after you deleted the `/abdi-teste/` directory right? So there must be a config where the server was pointing to that folder, which no longer exists.